Infinity category theory
I want to learn some $(\infty,1)$ categories as a beginner, and $(\infty,1)$ toposes. Is there any concise material(either book or lecture note) that one can suggest?
I am not a mathematics student, but a beginning physics grad student. So concise lecture notes/videos might be more helpful for me to start with.
Also, might like something with $(\infty,n)$ notions of toposes.
Thanks

Groth's Short Course comes to mind.

Julie Bergner has a survey paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610239
